# Fetch only years and calculated number of sales in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, graph, eloquent

I have a contracts table with customer and device ID, 
what I want to achieve is:

- **First**: fetch only all years from (from column)
- **Second**: calculate the total of device sold in that year show it on JavaScript Graph !

here is what I came so far:

**myControler**

```
public function getDashboardPage()
{
 $contracts = Contract::where('contract_type_id', '=', 2)
                ->whereNotNull('device_id')
                ->whereNotNull('customer_id')
                ->get();
  return view('dashboard.index')
            ->with('contracts ', $contracts );
```

**myView**

```
function morisChart(){

    var sales = {!! $contracts !!};
    var years= [];

    for (var j = 0; j < sales.length; j++) {
        years.push({
            year: sales[j].from.substr(0, 4)
        });
    }

    new Morris.Line({
      element: 'myfirstchart',
      data: years,
      xkey: 'year',
      ykeys: ['value'],
      labels: ['Devices Sold']
    });
}
```

[image: I want my graph to be same as this one]

[image]

where the contract_type_id 2 = sold.
I am having problem on fetching data on Graph this what I get

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: So what is your problem accomplishing your objective? Show us what you tried and what your current code  does or doesn't do...this isn't a free code writing service or a tutorial service

Comment: Are you using any sort of graphing library for javascript ?

Comment: I have updated my post :) @charlietfl

Comment: Ok...so you added some code....now what is the specific problem related to that code ?

Comment: my first problem ('from') field which returns dateTime couldnt format it using Carbon, Secondly, If you see the graph years label is looking so weird  I want it to be year by year according to my contract ('from') field.